# How to get Youtube channel information from the Channel ID on a Google sheet?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-sheets-api, youtube-javascript-api

I want to collect Youtube channel information from the Channel ID on a Google sheet.

Currently I am using the code below to collect Channel Informations by Channel Name ...which works pretty well.

What I want, now is to add another option to collect the same information by entering the Channel ID instead of the Channel Name.

Any idea what I have to change/add here:

Code example:

```
// Note: Apps Script automatically requests authorization
// based on the API's used in the code.

function channelsListByUsername(part, params) {
var response = YouTube.Channels.list(part,
                                   params);
var channel = response.items[0];
var dataRow = [channel.snippet.title, channel.id, 
channel.statistics.viewCount, channel.statistics.subscriberCount,];
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().appendRow(dataRow);
}


function getChannel() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var channelName = ui.prompt("Enter the channel name: ").getResponseText();
channelsListByUsername('snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
                     {'forUsername': channelName});
}


 function onOpen() {
 var firstCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).getValue();
 if (firstCell != 'Title') {
 var headerRow = ["Title", "ID", "View counts"];
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().appendRow(headerRow);
 }
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 ui.createMenu('YouTube Data')
 .addItem('Add channel name', 'getChannel')
 .addToUi();
 }
```

Comment: In order to help you we need to know what exactly is wrong with your current solution.   What is the output and what of the output is in correct.  what errors are you getting ect...

Comment: @DaImTo With the script above I have the option to enter the Channel name e.g. Usergames and getting the following informations: Title, ID and View Counts... which is ok.

But besides of entering the Channel Name I want to enter the Channel ID: UChcr0GhyXhxvNoXRvP2S6Tg

However I struggle with it. I though changing it to:

function channelsListByUsername(part, params) {
var response = YouTube.Channels.list(part,
                                   params);

would work but it didn't.